# Как работать с объединенными ячейками Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных, nan

Есть файл с объединенными ячейками ([пример файла](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xhwQsbMkHQsJ6du7VkLsyZ27a-tulvam7LsqSZ1n_aw/edit#gid=0)).

Пробывала так:

```
df1 = df1.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Но этот способ помогает заполнить ячейки, которые объединены по строкам, но не по столбцам:

[image: скриншот результата]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Методы `.fillna()`, `.ffill()`, `.bfill()` имеют параметр `axis`, указывающий по какой оси запольнять фрейм. По умолчанию это строки, но если явно задать `axis=1` или `axis="columns"` тогда заполнение будет происходить по столбцам:

```
res = df.ffill(axis=1)
```

Comment: да, работает. Спасибо.

Comment: через 10 минут приму ответ, сейчас не дает возможности